# Google Apps Scripts: Class notation and new Objects

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a class to import Google Sheets tables into a more maneuverable. The code:

```
class SheetData{
  constructor(worksheet, spreadsheet=null) {
    this.spreadsheet = spreadsheet ? spreadsheet : SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    this.sheet = this.spreadsheet.getSheetByName(worksheet);
    this.values = this.sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  }
  get records() {
    let cols = this.values[0], temp = {}, out = [];
    for (let row of this.values.slice(1)){
      cols.forEach( (colName,idx) => temp[colName] = row[idx] );
      out.push(temp);
      temp = {};
  }
}
```

How ever when I try to run it on a sheet `Logger.log(new SheetData('Sheet1').values)`, I get an `Unexpected identifier` at the `new`. What am I doing wrong? I also am not getting any syntax highlighting in the editor, even though I have the V8 runtime enabled.

Comment: I proposed a modified script by guessing your issue. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- If you are testing your script in your question, I think that in your script, `}` is required to be added at the last line (
  `}` is one shortage.).

  - I think that this might be the reason of your issue.
- And, `new SheetData('Sheet1').records` is run, `undefined` is returned. Because no value is returned.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
class SheetData{
  constructor(worksheet, spreadsheet=null) {
    this.spreadsheet = spreadsheet ? spreadsheet : SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    this.sheet = this.spreadsheet.getSheetByName(worksheet);
    this.values = this.sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  }
  get records() {
    let cols = this.values[0], temp = {}, out = [];
    for (let row of this.values.slice(1)){
      cols.forEach( (colName,idx) => temp[colName] = row[idx] );
      out.push(temp);
      temp = {};
    }
    return out; // <--- Added
  }
} // <--- Added

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  var s = new SheetData('Sheet1');
  console.log(s.values);  // or Logger.log(s.values);
  console.log(s.records);  // or Logger.log(s.records);
}
```

#### Note:

- Please confirm whether V8 runtime is enabled again.

Comment: I fixed both these issues, but it is still throwing unexpected identifier. V8 is indeed enabled.

Comment: @user3758912 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, in my environment, I can confirm that above modified script works and the values are returned. I apologize for this. And I'm not sure about your actual situation. So, for example, as a test case, how about creating new Google Apps Script project (standalone or container-bound script) and copying and pasting above script and then running it?

Comment: I was mistaken, it is returning the error on the return. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3758912 Thank you for replying. Can you provide the detail information about `I was mistaken, it is returning the error on the return.`? In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your current script? By this, I would like to confirm it. How about this?

Comment: @user3758912 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If you have a chance to find the reason of the issue and you provided it, I think that it might be useful for other users including me and also I can study from it. But it is not required to spend your time to find it. So don't worry.